# Using Custom Cursor WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mouse-cursor

Is there a way to use a custom cursor in winforms?

There seems to be no option. But when I try to manually add a cursor as a resource, then call it from code, it says that it cannot convert from type byte[] to Cursor.

Answer (score 12):

### Adding custom icon to cursor in C# :

Add Icon file to Project resources (ex : Processing.ico)

And in properties window of image switch "Build Action" to "Embedded"

```
Cursor cur = new Cursor(Properties.Resources.**Imagename**.Handle);
this.Cursor = cur;

Ex:

Cursor cur = new Cursor(Properties.Resources.Processing.Handle);
this.Cursor = cur;
```

Answer (score 6):

From the [MSDN documentation on the `Cursor` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) (with minor corrections):

```
// The following generates a cursor from an embedded resource.
// To add a custom cursor, create or use an existing 16x16 bitmap
//        1. Add a new cursor file to your project: 
//                File->Add New Item->Local Project Items->Cursor File
//        2. Select 16x16 image type:
//                Image->Current Icon Image Types->16x16
// --- To make the custom cursor an embedded resource  ---
// In Visual Studio:
//        1. Select the cursor file in the Solution Explorer
//        2. Choose View->Properties.
//        3. In the properties window switch "Build Action" to "Embedded"
// On the command line:
//        Add the following flag:
//            /res:CursorFileName.Cur,Namespace.CursorFileName.Cur
//        
//        Where "Namespace" is the namespace in which you want to use
//        the cursor and   "CursorFileName.Cur" is the cursor filename.
// The following line uses the namespace from the passed-in type
// and looks for CustomCursor.MyCursor.Cur in the assemblies manifest.
// NOTE: The cursor name is case sensitive.

this.Cursor = new Cursor(GetType(), "MyCursor.Cur");
```

Answer (score 2):

I've used the `LoadCursorFromFile()` method from User32.dll. There are plenty of samples for this on the web.

OR

The ctor for the `Cursor` type also has a `IO.Stream` overload. Load your `byte[]` into a `MemoryStream` and feed that to the new `Cursor`.

Comment: Yay! Thanks muchest @ondesertverge. The second option sound quite fun actually

Answer (score 2):

After adding the file to the resources, in the properties window of the image: switch `Build Action` to `Embedded Resource` and write in your code:

```
"name of control".Cursor = new System.Windows.Forms.Cursor(Properties.Resources."name of image".Handle);
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert your cursor from any format to ico using convertico.com(It is the best way of doing this), copy your cursor to your project's debug folder using file explorer and write this code(C#):

```
this.Cursor = new Cursor("default.ico");
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem for a while. So, as far as I understood, these are 2 ways to solving that issue:

1. Putting cursor .ico file into the Resources
2. Getting cursor from .ico file without putting it the resources

**First case:**
After putting to the resources you can just add `.Handle` after the name of resource while getting it. For instance:

`this.Cursor = new Cursor(Properties.Resources.YourResource.Handle);`

**Second case:**
This one looks a bit easier, but before that you should add your .ico file to project and in properties of that file you should set `Always copy` for file to be copied automatically to the execution folder. After that you can easyly use this:

`this.Cursor = new Cursor("YourIcon.ico");`

To my mind, using the resources for permanent files like cursor icons is the best practice, so the used the first one.