# Crosshair cursor with additional lines in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

how to make a crosshair cursor with help lines like this on screenshots:

[image]

I know how to make crosshire cursor:

```
 this.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Cross;
```

can be also something like that:

[image]

like in CAD software.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Custom Cursor WinForms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797084/using-custom-cursor-winforms)

Comment: You need to make a .cur file first. Then you may embed it to the assembly. As it mentioned above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the code I use.  x and y are the dimensions.  In my case I can have some text on the cursor and this is name.  If you want dots or dashes then you need to do that with the pen.

```
   private Cursor crossCursor(Pen pen, Brush brush, string name, int x, int y) {
            var pic = new Bitmap(x, y);
            Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(pic);

            var pathX = new GraphicsPath();
            var pathY = new GraphicsPath();
            pathX.AddLine(0, y / 2, x, y / 2);
            pathY.AddLine(x / 2, 0, x / 2, y);
            gr.DrawPath(pen, pathX);
            gr.DrawPath(pen, pathY);
            gr.DrawString(name, Font, brush, x / 2 + 5, y - 35);

            IntPtr ptr = pic.GetHicon();
            var c = new Cursor(ptr);
            return c;
        }
```

Comment: Nice job! ;) But if I were him/her I would use .cur (cursor) file.

Comment: Thankyou !  Fair enough.  I do it this way because the name value can change.  I have them different sizes and also have another overload that will put a bulls-eye on the cursor

Comment: I don't understand how to call this code inside my winform.

Comment: Something like Cursor = crossCursor(......) where Cursor is the cursor for the form or for some control within the form

Comment: Yep, got that now thanks. I have progressed this question though, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37542669/enhanced-crosshair-cursor-possible as I need things to work a bit differently.

Answer (score 0):

Just create two label box as **lab_X_Axis** and **lab_Y_Axis**.
In chart mousemove function code as shown below..

```
private void chart1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    lab_X_Axis.Location = new Point((e.X), 21);
    lab_Y_Axis.Location = new Point(76, e.Y);
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lab_X_Axis.AutoSize = false;
    lab_Y_Axis.AutoSize = false;
    lab_X_Axis.Text="";
    lab_Y_Axis.Text="";
    lab_X_Axes.Size = new Size(1, 300);
    lab_Y_Axes.Size = new Size(300, 1);
}
```

Comment: Please don't post duplicates, and please pay much closer attention to the questions you are answering.