# Custom image of cursor instead of system icon

Tags: c#, winforms

I have to set the custom image of cursor instead of predefined icon in c# winform.

But I want to set when system is busy or processing is happening in background and after completion his task then it back to its default setting.

I am using

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      Cursor.Current = new Cursor("D:\\hourglass.gif");
      try
      {
           Thread.Sleep(5000);  // wait for a while
      }
      finally
      {
          Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
      }
}
```

here I define the hourglass.gif which is custom image.
but it is through an error like below

"Argument 'picture' must be a picture that can be used as a Cursor.
Parameter name: picture"

Can you please assist me how to resolve it.

Comment: I am using below code

Comment: I am using Cursor.Current = new Cursor("C:\ic.gif"); code

Comment: Use search
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797084/using-custom-cursor-winforms

Comment: Setting Cursor.Current has little effect, set the form's Cursor property instead.  You can do so in the designer without writing any code.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0):

Consider converting the gif to a cursor:

http://www.gdgsoft.com/anituner/