# change mouse cursor to indian flag in C# windows application

Tags: c#, windows

I have an Indian flag cursor like sym66.cur and I used it in C# code. It is running 
but it is not getting in proper image. Instead, it is getting a black image. How can make the cursor display in the proper format?

This is my code:

```
private void New_Registration_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.Cursor = new Cursor(Application.StartupPath + "\\sym66.cur"); 
}
```

Comment: You need to provide more details about your situation.  Please make sure that you're attempting to load `sym66.cur` from a valid location (i.e. is `Application.StartupPath` really pointing to where you think it is?).  Perhaps this can help you:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797084/using-custom-cursor-winforms

Comment: Possibly the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305800/using-custom-colored-cursors-in-a-c-sharp-windows-application

Answer (score 0):

Q: Do you see a black square instead of a cursor ... or is your color cursor displaying in black and white.

The WinForms "Cursor" only supports black and white, not color:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
>
> The Cursor class does not support animated cursors (.ani files) or cursors with colors other than black and white.