# Where can I get the "open hand"/"closed hand" mouse cursors?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, mouse

I am looking for the *open hand* / *closed hand* mouse cursors à la Adobe Reader. Where are them? If they are non-standard, what's the easiest way for me to create them in C#?

[image: Hand cursors]

Comment: I don't think all programming questions have to be about STL containers or C++11 atomic operations. I have noticed that those two cursors, while very popular, are missing in Windows Forms (did you see the tags?). I am almost sure someone else has got this issue, and there might be smart (or less smart) ways to overcome it. Why shouldn't we share this information?

Comment: @SonerGönül this question is totally fine. Your argument does not hold.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, they are non-standard. Your just going to have to google around until you find them. Once you do check this out this answer - [Using Custom Cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2797101/2382032)

Btw - the standard cursors are [as follows.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Input.Cursors_properties(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: No problem, had a dead link I just fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old question, because I'm creating an image viewer right now, and was in need of same/similar cursors, I want to answer it.

I was trying to get the pan cursors from the Windows Photo Viewer, but I couldn't find them. So I decided to just capture them (screenshot) using [ShareX](https://getsharex.com/). I have removed the white pixels around the hands, and these are the results:

[image: pannable cursor]

[image]

The very edges of the original cursors are transparent. These are not. I'll fix that later.

And as a bonus, here are the pan cursors (png images) from Adobe Reader DC 2017:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Strictly speaking, I'm not entirely sure that's legal