# How to implement a userdefined cursor in C#?

Tags: c#, cursor

I want to define my own Cursor as the Current Cursor in my WPF Application, but wenn I try to create a new Cursor Object from my .cur File, I get an Error.

My Code is

```
     private void NewFile()
    {  ...

      iEvent_dragdrop = (HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event)doc;
      iEvent_dragdrop.ondragstart += new HTMLDocumentEvents2_ondragstartEventHandler(IEvent_ondragstart);         
    }

     private bool IEvent_ondragstart(IHTMLEventObj pEvtObj)
    {
        x_start = pEvtObj.x;           // Read position of Mouse
        y_start = pEvtObj.y;

        ....

        if (File.Exists("MyCursor.cur"))
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.Cursor myCursor = new System.Windows.Forms.Cursor(GetType(), "MyCursor.cur");
            System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = myCursor;
            //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("File exist");
        }
        else System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("File does not exist");

        return false;
    }
```

When I try to drag the HTML Object, I get the error System.NullReferenceException wasn´t handled in the source-code. But I tested if the File exists ....
Can anyone tell me, what´s my mistake?

Thanks!

Comment: "I get an Error." - What is it?

Comment: In System.NullReferenceException an exception occurs from the type "System.Windows.Forms.dll", but this wasn´t handled in the user-code... but I did an if(File.Exist("myCursor.cur") command before creating the new one

Comment: Please edit your post with the error description, line of occurrence and all of the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [searching the web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797084/using-custom-cursor-winforms) before asking. First search result for the title explains everything you should need to know.

Try this out:

```
class Program {
    [System.STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        byte[] cursorBytes = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadData(@"https://github.com/tlorach/nvGraphy/raw/master/cursor1.cur");
        System.IO.Stream cursorStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(cursorBytes, false);
        System.Windows.Forms.Cursor cursor = new System.Windows.Forms.Cursor(cursorStream);
        System.Windows.Forms.Form mainForm = new System.Windows.Forms.Form();
        mainForm.Cursor = cursor;
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(mainForm);
    }
}
```

Or this:

```
class Program {
    [System.STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog openDialog = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
        openDialog.Filter = "Cursor (*.cur)|*.cur";
        switch(openDialog.ShowDialog()) {
            case System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK:
                System.Windows.Forms.Cursor cursor = new System.Windows.Forms.Cursor(openDialog.FileName);
                System.Windows.Forms.Form mainForm = new System.Windows.Forms.Form();
                mainForm.Cursor = cursor;
                System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(mainForm);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't raise more flags for this question ;)

Comment: Thanks. But is there a way to generate a cursor not from an embedded resource but from a resource on my pc?