# How can I change the color of my cursor while in a textbox in UWP C#

Tags: c#, uwp, cursor

Hello I am developing an app using C# UWP.  I have a text box, when I click on the text box the cursor flashes black and white awaiting the next letter.  my question is, is there a way to change the color of this cursor? for example changing it so it flashes red and blue instead of black and white. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Custom Cursor WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797084/using-custom-cursor-winforms)

Comment: Are you trying to change the color of the cursor (mouse pointer) or the caret which is the blinking vertical bar in the textbox?

Comment: This is currently not possible in UWP.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I want to change the color of the caret

Answer (score 0):

As Justin XL said there is no such api to change color of cursor currently. In another way, 
if you feel that the cursor color is not bright enough, you can try to change the TextBox background or the forgorund color to let cursor appear bright. If you do want this feature, please feel free to submit feature request on [**UserVoice**](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform).