# using IntPtr form other class

Tags: c#

I am using custom cursor for textbox

this method and it's work fine for me

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr LoadCursorFromFile(string lpFileName);
```

```
IntPtr Search_cursor = LoadCursorFromFile(Application.StartupPath + "\\SearchCursor.cur");

txt_Vacation_Calculate_Type_Code.Cursor = new Cursor(Search_cursor);
```

but I need using this method from other class
I have created Class `Image_Icon`

```
class Image_Icon
{
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr LoadCursorFromFile(string lpFileName);

public IntPtr Search_cursor_C()
{
IntPtr Search_cursor = LoadCursorFromFile(Application.StartupPath + "\\SearchCursor.cur");
return (Search_cursor);
}
```

i am using this code for get Cursor

```
txt_Vacation_Calculate_Type_Code.Cursor = new Cursor(Image_Icon.Search_cursor_C);
```

But it looks like something is wrong
i get this error

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'IntPtr'  PayRoll C:\Users\Ahmed Abdo\Desktop\WorkNow\PayRoll\PayRoll\PayRoll\Basis\frmEmployeeData.cs    68  Active

how can access this class from other class and using search cursor

Comment: you need to call `Search_cursor_C` method ... also it should be static or you should call it from class instance ... also please take some C# course ... if you are getting compile time error mostly it means that you don't know language(or making typos)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Custom Cursor WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797084/using-custom-cursor-winforms)

Comment: @ Selvin  ... ok

Comment: this method not working in windows 7 

look here 


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64432179/image-format-is-not-valid-the-image-file-may-be-corrupted-in-win7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your function static, and return `Cursor`:

```
class Image_Icon
{

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr LoadCursorFromFile(string lpFileName);

    public static Cursor Search_cursor_C()
    {
        return new Cursor(LoadCursorFromFile(System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "SearchCursor.cur")));
    }

}
```

Then use it like this:

```
txt_Vacation_Calculate_Type_Code.Cursor = Image_Icon.Search_cursor_C();
```