# Custom cursor image missing "Handle" in Windows Forms application

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing a Windows Forms application in C#, and I'm trying to set a custom cursor for a control using the Cursor class. However, I'm encountering an issue where my custom cursor image doesn't have a "Handle" property, as mentioned in the provided Stack Overflow link ([Using Custom Cursor WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797084/using-custom-cursor-winforms)).

I have followed the steps outlined in the link, including placing the custom cursor file (in .cur format) in my project's resources and setting the "Build Action" of the cursor file to "Embedded Resource". However, when attempting to load the cursor using new Cursor(typeof(Program), "cursor.cur"), the cursor object doesn't have the "Handle" property, which is required to set the cursor for a control.

Can someone please guide me on how to resolve this issue? Is there an alternative way to set a custom cursor in a Windows Forms application when the cursor image doesn't have a "Handle"? Any insights or code examples would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You can load a Cursor from resources using the Form's Type and the Resource name (`new Cursor(GetType(), "[Resource Name]")`), or read it as a Stream (with, e.g., `Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(typeof(Cursor), "[Resource Name]"`)), not necessarily from an Icon